# Changing the content of a website completely, and SEO

Tags: seo, content

I have a blog running since like 10 months, which have 300 organic unique visitors daily, and now I will establish an eCommerce website on that domain.

That means, I will delete all the content related to the blog. And publish new pages related to eCommerce using a different script. Content of the blog and the topic of eCommerce are also quite different.

How should i do this change in terms of SEO?

What should I expect in terms of Search Rankings, organic hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting from scratch. Your content is changing, your markup is changing, and your incoming links are virtually useless since they are now unrelated to your new content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching the eCommerce product related to the content on the blog then my suggestion is to keep the blog and launch the eCommerce section as a new module on the site. Then you just need to lead your visitors from the blog to the eCommerce module using appropriate call to action elements.

IF you delete the content on the blog , you lose all the incoming links ( unless you do a 301 redirects for those pages , in which case you can salvage some link juice )